# IOS error inserting data on sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

i am on final project making GOLyrics apps for ios. my apps can search lyric and favorited it. but i have problems in my add favorite lyric, and i do not know why, im newbie in objective C especially in ios programming. help me please.

here's my add to favorite method:

```
  -(void)insertFav:(Favorite*)favssssdsd{

fileMgrs = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;

NSString *sqlQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT or REPLACE INTO fav (username,title,artist,image,song,lyric) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@');",favssssdsd.username,favssssdsd.lirikTitle,favssssdsd.lirikArtist,favssssdsd.lirikImage,favssssdsd.lirikSong,favssssdsd.lirik];
NSLog(@"query:%@",sqlQuery);
const char *sql =[sqlQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//NSLog(@"row:%d",row);
//Open db
NSString *cruddatabase = [self.GetCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TB.sqlite"];
sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &db);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
@try
{
    if(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Succes insert fav");
    }
    else  NSLog(@"failed insert fav");


}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
}

sqlite3_reset(stmt);

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);
   }
```

the output is :

```
TestYey[1505:47536] query:INSERT or REPLACE INTO fav      (username,title,artist,image,song,lyric) VALUES ('shasapo','Stay','Rihanna','18.jpg','Stay.mp3','the lyrics in here');

TestYey[1505:47536] failed insert fav
```

Someone help me please :")
i dont know why it isn't inserting

Comment: first time making it, it success. but now it doesnt work.

Comment: check your sql query in Sqlite Manager.

Comment: Try after Reset your simulator.

Comment: i've check the query, it works perfectly in sqlite manager. and i've reset my simulator, still doesnt work

Comment: I think it is problem of your database path..check it properlly.add Break point and check where app stuck.

Comment: actually i have one method exactly like this method, it is " registerNewMember", the difference only in the query. 

the register method work perfectly, but this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should check which code retuned from sqlite3_step(stmt) in else clause. That will help you to figure out what's wrong.
2. Second improvement -

I suggest you to use sqlite3_bind_ functions:

```
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int n, void(*)(void*));
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_double(sqlite3_stmt*, int, double);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_int64(sqlite3_stmt*, int, sqlite3_int64);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_null(sqlite3_stmt*, int);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const char*, int n, void(*)(void*));
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_text16(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int, void(*)(void*));
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_value(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const sqlite3_value*);
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_bind_zeroblob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int n);
and check if sqlite3_prepare_v2 returns 'OK' result.
```

And rewrite your method as

```
-(void)insertFav:(Favorite*)favssssdsd{

    fileMgrs = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;


    char sql[] ="INSERT or REPLACE INTO fav (username,title,artist,image,song,lyric) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    NSString *cruddatabase = [self.GetCacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TB.sqlite"];

    if (sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
       NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
        return;
    }

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        int bindRes = 0;
        bindRes = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [favssssdsd.username UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        bindRes = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [favssssdsd.lirikTitle UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        bindRes = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [favssssdsd.lirikArtist UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        bindRes = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [favssssdsd.lirikImage UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        bindRes = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [favssssdsd.lirikSong UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        bindRes = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [favssssdsd.lirik UTF8String],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Succes insert fav");
        }
        else  NSLog(@"failed insert fav");


    }


    sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Set up breakpoint on you bindRes and check where is the problem.

**NOTE** i don't know exactly which type have your properties, so you should rewrite bind functions, if needed. i use bind_text (for NSString binding)

Hope this help